# How do I get more stars for my Tower?

Tags: simtower

It has been a long time since I played Sim Tower. I vaguely recall that getting more stars means I can build certain things, but I forget how I can increase my star count.

How do I get more stars for my Tower?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**STAR: 1**

> POP: 0
>
> Requirement: None
>
> NEW IMPROVEMENTS: Lobby, Blank Floor, Stairs, Standard Elevator,
>   Office, Fast Food, and Condo

---

**STAR: 2**

> POP: 300
>
> Requirement: None
>
> NEW IMPROVEMENTS: Security Office, Service
>   Elevator, Single Hotel Room, and Housekeeping Office

---

**STAR: 3**

> POP: 1000
>
> Requirement: More than one Security Office
>
> NEW IMPROVEMENTS: Escalator, Express Elevator, Restaurant, Retail
>   Shop, Party Hall, Movie Theater, Parking Space, Parking Ramp,
>   Recycling Center, Medical Center, Double Hotel Room, Hotel Suite

---

**STAR: 4**

> POP: 5000
>
> Requirement: More than one Hotel Suite, VIP approval,
>   Recycling, Medical and parking requirements met.
>
> NEW IMPROVEMENTS: Metro Station

---

**STAR: 5**

> POP: 10,000
>
> Requirement: Metro Station
>
> NEW IMPROVEMENTS: Cathedral

---

**STAR: Tower**

> POP: 15,000
>
> Requirement: Cathedral
>
> NEW IMPROVEMENTS: None

Comment: Improved formatting so you can actually read it. XD